# How can I get follow-up elements from an array element?

Tags: php, arrays, file

I am trying to get a specific line in a file and then next 2 lines after it. How can I get next 2 lines? The following is my code and file.

```
$context = 'context=regencyoutgoing';
$lines = file('/etc/asterisk/sip1.conf');
foreach($lines as $line)
{
    $find_context = strpos($line, $context);
    if($find_context !== false){
        echo $line;
    }
}
```

Here is my `sip1.conf`:

```
[000201891]
type=friend
context=regencyoutgoing
username=000201891
callerid = <000201891>
host=dynamic
secret=198



[000202222]
type=friend
context=regencyoutgoing
username=000202222
callerid = <000202222>
host=dynamic
secret=2000
```

Comment: So where are we with this question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

First of all we get all array elements, which contain `$context` somewhere with [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php). In your example something like this:

```
Array
(
    2  => context=regencyoutgoing
    12 => context=regencyoutgoing
)
```

After this we get the keys of the array with [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php). Then we simply loop through all keys and take a slice of 3 elements for each key with [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php), which we then merge to the result array with [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

Code:

```
 <?php

    $lines = file("/etc/asterisk/sip1.conf");
    $context = "context=regencyoutgoing";
    $matchedKeys = array_keys(preg_grep("/" . preg_qute($context, "/")  ."/", $lines));
    $result = [];

    foreach($matchedKeys as $key)
        $result = array_merge($result, array_slice($lines, $key, 3));

    print_r($result);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This file is actually in `.ini` format, so you can try using [`parse_ini_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) to read this.

```
$data = parse_ini_file('/etc/asterisk/sip1.conf', TRUE);
```

This gives you an associative array that you can then loop/search through as you need.

Example: https://eval.in/438391

Comment: i used it but it gives me following message. i checked the sip1.conf but there is no problem. PHP Warning:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in sip1.conf on line 978 in /scripts/a.php on line 15

Comment: @Khan: Maybe it's not *entirely* an `.ini` file, then.  The snippet you showed us was, though.  Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$result=[];
foreach($lines as $i => $line)
{
    $find_context = strpos($line, $context);
    if($find_context !== false){
        $result=[$lines[$i],$lines[$i+1],$lines[$i+2]];

    }
}
```

Example: https://eval.in/438416

Comment: 1) Since the array element could be at the end you need to check if the 2 follow up elements exists or not 2) You loop through the entire array, which might be not so clever if you have an array with 10k elements and just want to grab 2 elements or so